# Difference beetwen that kinds of Dependency Injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a quick question about dependecy injection in Spring. I have two dummy classes both of them using little bit different approach and here araise the question. Which is better and why?

```
FIRST APPROACH
public class ClassName {
   private final Object obj;

   public ClassName(Object obj){
      this.obj = obj;
}
```

```
SECOND APPROACH
public class ClassName {
   private Object obj;

   @Autowired
   public ClassName(Object obj){
       this.obj = obj;
}
```

Comment: Assuming these are `@Component`s (or related stereotype), there is no difference besides a superfluous annotation in the second one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in between two because they only have one constructor. The only case you should use `@Autowired` on a constructor when doing a dependency injection while having multiple constructors. Eg:

```
@Component
public class ClassName {
    final Object obj;

    public ClassName() {
        this.obj = null; // null or something else
    }

    @Autowired
    public ClassName(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}
```

If you don't use `@Autowired` on the constructor you intent to initialize defaults with then no-arg constructor will be selected. So in above case if you omit `@Autowired` then the value for `obj` will be set to `null`.